# caroufredsel with prettyphoto and chrome

Tags: jquery, css, prettyphoto, caroufredsel

I am using carouFredSel slider for images, everything words great, I integrated prettyPhoto with it, that works perfectly in Firefox, but in Chrome / Safari the main image doesnt load, if i remove prettyPhoto image here it loads fine in Chrome as well, I tried my best to sort out the problem, but couldn't find a solution..

any idea what could be wrong ? may be its something to do with prettyPhoto OR carouFredsel ?

regards

Comment: here is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/n9XUL/

Comment: I think stakoverflow should make it easy to pst code :( its really hard, my actual post also as the code, but not visisble, it should be simply to post code like [code]<php echo "Please fix stackoverflow"; ?>[/code]

Comment: here is the example as ZIP file, i didn't added CSS files of prettyphoto.. : http://www.freefilehosting.net/coolcarousel2

Answer (score 0):

ok I found a fix, hopefully will help someone.. you only need to add the following css code to make it work with Chrome and Safari..

```
#slider_images a {
display: block;
float: left;
}
```